# Issues with go:embed directive: Invalid name

Tags: go

I want to serve music from my HDD. All audio files (mp3/flac/etc.) are read-only. so using //go:embed should work for those files. So I have

```
//go:embed "assets/Media/Music/*"
var f embed.FS

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.StaticFS("/public", http.FS(f))
    router.GET("/", func(c *gin.Context) {
        file, _ := f.ReadFile("assets/Media/Music/<some_other_folders>/01 - my_song.mp3")
        c.Data(
            http.StatusOK,
            "audio/mpeg",
            file,
        )
    }

    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

The problem is that the Go compiler complains that certain folder names are invalid for example: 'Big K.R.I.T' and 'Al B. Sure!' The docs say that file names shouldn't have spaces or '.' but I'm unaware if that applies if I don't explicitly state the file/folder name.

My question is

1. What constitutes a "invalid name"
2. Is there a way to allow folder names with spaces for the embed directive

**EDIT**

The code above is (almost) exactly what I'm running locally. When I try to build (or go run main.go) VS Code [catches this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8K4w.png). The ending is a *folder name* and not a file for clarification. Hopefully this helps. Thanks in advance

Comment: Embedding all music files is not a good idea. Embedded files will be copied, included in the final executable binary. So if you have 100 GB audio files, your executable will be bigger than 100 GB.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `*` if you want to recursively include an entire directory tree. `//go:embed "assets/Media/Music"` should suffice. Spaces, dots or exclamation points should not be an issue either. You are already using the technique to include a directory with spaces, by wrapping the path in double-quotes.

Comment: Yes, I tried a folder with space in its name, and a file named `Al B. Sure!` in it and it worked. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @icza thanks for the response. I plan on setting up gin streaming for audio later down the line, ideally right now i want to get album artwork setup as assets. Hopefully it doesn't increase the binary size by a ton. Or do you recommend also using a gin stream for the images as well?

Comment: It would appear this question has way more subtleties than I had first thought. I've posted the details below after traversing the go source for the exact filename validation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Consulting the `go` command [src](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.17.1/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L2055) where the `invalid name` error is emitted:

```
if elem := filepath.Base(dir); isBadEmbedName(elem) {
    if dir == file {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot embed %s %s: invalid name %s", what, rel, elem)
    } else {
        return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("cannot embed %s %s: in invalid directory %s", what, rel, elem)
    }
}
```

This references [isBadEmbedName](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.17.1/src/cmd/go/internal/load/pkg.go#L2136) which then relies on the function [module.CheckFilePath](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/mod/+/refs/tags/v0.5.1:module/module.go;l=488). The docs for this function states:

```
// CheckFilePath checks that a slash-separated file path is valid.
// The definition of a valid file path is the same as the definition
// of a valid import path except that the set of allowed characters is larger:
// all Unicode letters, ASCII digits, the ASCII space character (U+0020),
// and the ASCII punctuation characters
// “!#$%&()+,-.=@[]^_{}~”.
// (The excluded punctuation characters, " * < > ? ` ' | / \ and :,
// have special meanings in certain shells or operating systems.)
//
// CheckFilePath may be less restrictive in the future, but see the
// top-level package documentation for additional information about
// subtleties of Unicode.
```

So it would appear - based on the last line - that the embedded filename rules is a moving target.

---

Running some tests against this validation function, show even more subtleties e.g. `dot.in.middle` vs `dot.at.end.`:

https://play.golang.org/p/7x6i_Aj8eEJ

so this would explain why your path `Big K.R.I.T.` fails.

---

Also worthy of note: when using the `//go:embed` directive with a wildcard or not affects compilation success.

As you experienced, your compilation failed when using:

```
//go:embed "assets/Media/Music/*"
var f embed.FS
```

due to the invalid filename format in that directory. However, if you drop the wildcard:

```
//go:embed "assets/Media/Music"
var f embed.FS
```

compilation will succeed - but any invalid filenames will just be silently removed from the embed manifest.

---

If you want to inspect explicitly what files will be embedded in your program, you can avail of `go list` e.g.

```
go list -json
```

and look for the `EmbedFiles` section of the output. Or use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) to zero-in on this section:

```
$ go list -json | jq .EmbedFiles

[
  "Static Files/Space Dir/Big K.R.I.T.mp3",
  "Static Files/Space Dir/world.txt",
  "Static Files/hey!"
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated response. I was just playing around with the dir names and discovered the "dot.at.end." issue. I'm curious if this is an issue that should be reported as a bug or if this is a intended design choice.

Comment: The edge cases are certainly odd. Is it a bug? Probably not - since the `go:embed` directive is not really meant for user content - but more for static assets which have less adventurous filenames. If you need to capture a filesystem, formats like `tar` may be a better option.